# Compound interest with additions

Tags: code-golf, math

You have been given the charge to calculate the current balance as of the day that you perform the calculation for 330,000 individuals who worked for an average of 30 years spanning 300 years where the initial principal was `1` with an addition of `1` per day and interest rate set at `3%`.

You initially tried to use online compound interest with additions calculators to compute the sum. But all 10 calculators you tried had different results due to rounding errors. You decide to compose your own code which will assist in completing your charge.

### Input

Your task is write a function `f` which takes as input

- *`p`* Principal. A positive integer or decimal reflecting initial deposit.
- *`r`* Rate. A positive decimal reflecting the annual interest rate.
- *`t`* Time. An positive integer reflecting years to compute the compounding interest with additions.
- *`n`* Periods. A positive integer reflecting the number of periods per year to compound interest.
- *`a`* Addition. A positive integer or decimal which will be added to the current principal at the end of each period. Any number of additions can be deposited during *`t`*; for example, `10` additions of `20` can be deposited in a single day, or no deposits can be made during a period. For this question *`a`* will be a constant value, to avoid confusing users who expect output to be a single, consistent value.

### Output

The output can be an array of \$n\$ arrays of numbers, where each element is `[year, day, days, principal]` as follows:

- *`year`* The year as a positive integer within *`t`* years.
- *`doy`* (day of year): The day number within a year; \$0 \le\$ day \$\le 360\$ e.g. `days = 460` implies `year = 2` and `doy = 100$`.
- *`days`* The number of days since the initial deposit *`p`* was made.
- *`balance`* The current balance.

Other acceptable output formats:

- The above, but with elements of each array in a different (consistent) order;
- List of comma or space-delimited strings;
- The above, joined by newlines or tabs;
- `JSON` string representation of an array of objects;
- Spreadsheet;
- Any other formats permitted by default.

### Important

- Interest is compounded at the **end** of each period, which produces a new principal beginning at the next period. The addition, if any, is added to the new principal after interest is applied at the end of the period.
- "Leap day" and "leap years" are irrelevant to the question. The requirement for this question is to use the constant banker's year consisting of `360` days.

### Example

**Input**

```
p=1,r=0.03,t=1,n=12,a=10
```

**Output** (truncated, see stacksnippet). You need not output the labels "year", "day", etc.

```
[
      {
        "year": 1,
        "doy": 0,
        "days": 0,
        "balance": 1,
        "rate": 0.03,
        "addition": 0
      },
      { "year": 1, 
        "doy": 30, 
        "days": 30, 
        "balance": 11.0025,
        "rate": 0.03,
        "addition": 10
      },...
      {
        "year": 1,
        "doy": 180,
        "days": 180,
        "balance": 61.391346409181246,
        "rate": 0.03,
        "addition": 10
      },...
      {
        "year": 1,
        "doy": 360,
        "days": 360,
        "balance": 122.69424361094278,
        "rate": 0.03,
        "addition": 10
      }
]
```

```html
[
  {
    "year": 1,
    "DOY": 0,
    "days": 0,
    "balance": 1,
    "rate": 0.03,
    "addition": 0
  },
  {
    "year": 1,
    "DOY": 30,
    "days": 30,
    "balance": 11.0025,
    "rate": 0.03,
    "addition": 10
  },
  {
    "year": 1,
    "DOY": 60,
    "days": 60,
    "balance": 21.03000625,
    "rate": 0.03,
    "addition": 10
  },
  {
    "year": 1,
    "DOY": 90,
    "days": 90,
    "balance": 31.082581265625,
    "rate": 0.03,
    "addition": 10
  },
  {
    "year": 1,
    "DOY": 120,
    "days": 120,
    "balance": 41.160287718789064,
    "rate": 0.03,
    "addition": 10
  },
  {
    "year": 1,
    "DOY": 150,
    "days": 150,
    "balance": 51.26318843808603,
    "rate": 0.03,
    "addition": 10
  },
  {
    "year": 1,
    "DOY": 180,
    "days": 180,
    "balance": 61.391346409181246,
    "rate": 0.03,
    "addition": 10
  },
  {
    "year": 1,
    "DOY": 210,
    "days": 210,
    "balance": 71.5448247752042,
    "rate": 0.03,
    "addition": 10
  },
  {
    "year": 1,
    "DOY": 240,
    "days": 240,
    "balance": 81.72368683714221,
    "rate": 0.03,
    "addition": 10
  },
  {
    "year": 1,
    "DOY": 270,
    "days": 270,
    "balance": 91.92799605423507,
    "rate": 0.03,
    "addition": 10
  },
  {
    "year": 1,
    "DOY": 300,
    "days": 300,
    "balance": 102.15781604437065,
    "rate": 0.03,
    "addition": 10
  },
  {
    "year": 1,
    "DOY": 330,
    "days": 330,
    "balance": 112.41321058448158,
    "rate": 0.03,
    "addition": 10
  },
  {
    "year": 1,
    "DOY": 360,
    "days": 360,
    "balance": 122.69424361094278,
    "rate": 0.03,
    "addition": 10
  }
]
```

### Formula

You can use the formula at [Saving and Investing](http://www.math.fsu.edu/~blackw/mgf1107fa06/Saving.pdf)

> If **D** represents the amount of a regular deposit, **r** the annual
>   interest rate expressed as a decimal, **m** the number of equal
>   compounding period (in a year), and **t** time in years, then the
>   future value, **F**, of the account, is:
>
> [image]

or any comparable formula which determines a future value that you decide or is available at the language that you use, for example the formulas located at

- [Continually Compounded Interest + Addition to Principal](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/118616/138305)
- [Compound Interest Formula adding annual contributions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1698578/138305)

### Winning criteria

Shortest code in bytes.

Comment: Output format is a bit restrictive. What should we do in languages without objects?  Also, can we return a function `f` such that `f(42,"year")` displays the value of the "year" field in the 42nd object, and calling f on anything that's not not "year", "day", "days", "principal", "rate", or "addition" is undefined behavior?

Comment: @lirtosiast Does the language provide a means to out strings? If yes, then output can be `JSON`; see the question at _"or `JSON` string"_. Not fully gathering the second sentence, as yet. The output should be the entire graph for the total duration of _`t`_, including an entry for every _`n`_.

Comment: This is oddly restrictive, and resembles some kind of homework problem to me. Was this sandboxed?

Comment: @Gigaflop What do you mean by _"oddly restrictive"_? Be specific. No, not "homework". No, not "sandboxed".

Comment: Is someone trying to get PP&CG to write their commercial finance code? I think we should be told.

Comment: @J.Doe Why do you suspect the question is not the truth? Have you actually tried to derive the result at the question following the suggestion to try 10 different online calculators with the input provided at the question? Have already achieved the requirement, thus the proof at the example at the question. If you determine that the results at the example at the question are not accurate, kindly state that so the algorithm can be corrected. The question is tagged code-golf.

Comment: @guest271314 By oddly restrictive, I mean that the output format seems to be very restrictive such that it might disqualify some of the most popular languages used. Furthermore, the information in the output could effectively be conveyed at each step rather than all at the end, and communicate the same information. I don't see any real reason for such an inflexible output format.

Comment: @Gigaflop This is not a popularity contest. If the language is "popular", in your view, it should have enough developers contributing to the code base to solve such a question. There is no difference between writing code that reproduces the entire graph and that outputs a single entry in the graph. The code must be capable of achieving the entire output, and demonstrate that.

Comment: With those types of comments you will only get downvotes... #justSaying

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz _"With those types of comments you will only get downvotes... #justSaying"_ What are you talking about? Am not concerned with emotional responses to the question, or comments thereabout. The question does not ask for a group hug. Answer the coding question. Or not.

Comment: @guest271314, please leave your attitude at the door, take some time to learn what this site is *about*, listen to the advice being offered to you in order to *help* you improve your challenges and, above all, start using the Sandbox. All but one of your challenges have been poorly received and your continued response to those trying to help you out has been to resort to throwing insults around.

Comment: @Shaggy There have been no "attitude" or "insults" made by this user at all. If an individual interprets direct communication as such, that is their emotional issue and has absolutely nothing to do with the question or coding at all. Output can be in a wide range of options which are not complicated at all. Choose the language which produces output that meets the criteria at the question.

Comment: @guest271314 I don't object to your being direct nor do I downvote questions for that reason. Personally I think there *is* room on this site for well-written challenges targeted at certain classes of languages, even as the majority of questions on this site move away from it. However, there are strong consensus on meta that challenges should be written so that most languages can participate, that jumping through hoops to fit an output format removes fun, and that creators of a challenge should edit challenges to fit community guidelines. If you disagree, make a persuasive argument on meta.

Comment: @lirtosiast The output format is not restrictive, nor was it intended to be restrictive as part of the challenge. meta is a different domain altogether. Am not trying to convince any user of anything. How exactly is the string as `JSON` or array `[{"year": 1,
        "day": 0,
        "days": 0,
        "principal": 1,
        "rate": 0.03,
        "addition": 0}]`, or as a table, or as a spreadsheet, restrictive? Which languages are _restricted_ from producing such output?

Comment: @lirtosiast [Are any languages restricted from producing JSON?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17116/31257)

Comment: @Gigaflop See updated question.

Comment: Can we output an array of arrays of just the values without the labels?

Comment: @Quintec Yes. Output formatting is not intended to be a restriction or challenge. We simply need to have uniform output; to be aware of what the values represent as to input at each answer.

Comment: @JoKing _`day`_ is the day of a banker's year `360` which resets to `0` after each new _`t`_. _`days`_ reflect the sum of all `day`s, does not reset to `0` after each _`t`_. The example only demonstrates a single _`t`_, thus the update of _`days`_ is not printed. _`days`_ would be `361` at the start of _`t`_ `2`, _`day`_ would be reset to _`0`_.

Comment: @JoKing Yes, for uniformity. Ideally, although not specifically stated, the function should be able to be adjusted to handle more than one additions and no additions during a given period; omitted from the question to avoid confusion as to the requirement and verifying output. Variable additions and rates would perhaps add complexity to the question which would lead to users' not being clear as to what the expected output is.

Comment: Ideally? Is that part of the challenge?

Comment: @Quintec No. Users would invariably state that the question or output is not clear. Would have to test for each variation of possible addition and interest rate, which is exhaustive. However, we should have all of the relevant values on each line or element of array produced as a discrete unit; so that we know the extent of the dataset that we are examining. When rate or addition are omitted from a discrete output unit those variables are unknowns as to the remainder of the values without reverse engineering, and ultimately, guessing.

Comment: @JoKing An alternative would be to output `rate` and `addition` once at the first field of output, since we are only dealing with a single `addition` value per `n` and fixed `rate` per `t` at this question. Would that address the consideration of not repeating the code or output?

Comment: @JoKing Updated to remove requirement to output `rate` and `addition`.

Comment: "*Accuracy **must** be to at least 14 decimal places*". This is impossible using IEEE 754 double width numbers unless you add some tight constraints which ensure that the final value doesn't exceed about 10. If your intention is that all answers must use a type like Java's BigDecimal then you should make that explicit.

Comment: Is the addition of `a` before or after interest is calculated?

Comment: The section on output doesn't asks for an array of objects but doesn't say how many. Is it one for each period? What if the periods aren't an integral number of days (as very few are)? How are leap years handled? If the output is supposed to be for one year, why does it not end on year 2, day 0?

Comment: @PeterTaylor 1. Output at least up to 14 decimal places. One output for every period. A banker's year is 360 days, as stated in the question.

Comment: @Dennis What is not clear to you in the question?

Comment: @guest271314 https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/176247/compound-interest-with-additions#comment424380_176247 is still not clarified for example. We understand that you're requiring that output must be at least accurate up to 14 decimal places, but your response didn't address the issue.

Comment: In case you don't understand IEEE 754 etc.: Built-in floating point type in most languages has only about 16 decimal digits of precision. If the integer part has more than ~3 digits then there are only <14 digits of precision for the fractional part, which may be impossible to represent some values. For example 1000000000.000000001 cannot be represented "accurate to 14 decimal places" using Javascript's default number type.

Comment: @user202729 The point is to produce output up to 14 decimal points - where possible - to evaluate how different languages or approaches to solving the question produce different results, see https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/176247/compound-interest-with-additions#comment424359_176260 where the observation was noted, though does not make the answer or the result derived using JavaScript necessarily incorrect. https://www.mathsisfun.com/accuracy-precision.html.

Comment: @user202729 Is the only part of the question that is porportedly "unclear" to users the output? If that is the case what constructive suggestion do you have to resolve users' apparent confusion as to output? Or, is there another reason users voted to close the question as "unclear"? _"Bias (don't let precision fool you!)
When we measure something several times and all values are close, they may all be wrong if there is a "Bias"

**Bias is a systematic (built-in) error which makes all measurements wrong by a certain amount.**"_ https://www.mathsisfun.com/accuracy-precision.html

Comment: @user202729 The question does not ask to produce the exact same output the BIS would produce for the same input. The question merely asks to produce the output using the language of the users' choice, golfed, up to a reasonable or possible decimal point where comparisons of the output can be made; given the fact that output from online calculators, including gov'ment calculators, is not consistent. Again, what is "unclear" in the text of the question, and what needs to be edited to make the question clear to those users who vote to close the question citing "unclear"?

Comment: @user202729 Updated question. Does that resolve that concern as to computation and output?

Comment: @PeterTaylor "Leap day" does not affect the question whatsoever. The contract at the question uses 360-day years exclusively. Updated the question as to decimal points. Do the edits clarify the question to you?

Comment: @PeterTaylor _"..it depends on how the interest on your mortgage is calculated and whether it is done so on a 360- or 365-day year.
Most mortgages... accrue interest based on a monthly rate, which is calculated by simply dividing the annual rate by 12. That number is then multiplied by the loan balance to determine the monthly interest amount. Since it uses a generic month, or 1/12th of a year, it makes no difference is that month has 30 days, 31 days, 28 days or 29 days"_ https://www.thearamcogroup.com/Blog/bid/126773/Does-Leap-Day-Have-Any-Impact-On-A-Mortgage

Comment: Does "The principal must not be rounded" mean "must not be rounded to the nearest integer" or "must be exact"?

Comment: I raised six points. You have edited the question to fix the first one. That leaves five.

Comment: @lirtosiast The previous description asked for 14 decimal places. Must not be rounded means your code does not directly perform a mathematical operation to round the result. Output whatever your language outputs, following the formula at the question, or whatever formula you choose to use.

Comment: @PeterTaylor _"Is the addition of a before or after interest is calculated?"_ is directly answered at the question by both a textual description and the formula used. The updated question resolves your other inquiries, as _" If the output is supposed to be for one year, why does it not end on year 2, day 0?"_ is a nitpick that has no relevance to the question, correct? If not, kindly number what you mean by "six points".

Comment: "*...directly answered at the question by both a textual description*" where? "*The updated question resolves your other inquiries*" where? And when? The only update to the question changed "*Accuracy must be to at least 14 decimal places.*" to "*Include the decimal portion of the number, if any is produced by the language that you decide to use to compute the period, in the output.*".

Comment: "*a nitpick that has no relevance to the question, correct?*" No. I want to know if answers are required to special-case the last entry.

Comment: @guest271314 Made some edits to the question. Change them again if they don't match your intention.

Comment: @lirtosiast Balance is the current principal when the computation is made. "DOY" should be lowercase, to match the other properties case?

Comment: @guest271314 I don't think case matters when no competitive answer will bother printing it anyway.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Your concerns are not clearly delineated as number 1-6. The decimal portion of question should be clear now. The "special case", as you refer to the 13 entries where interest is accrued for only 12 periods, at the example at the question, is to present the _first_ entry in the output. Unless we can get the algorithm that the Bank for International Settlements uses, what algorithm do you suggest we rely on for the definitive formula to calculate compound interest with additions or contributions; that we will compare output to?

Comment: @lirtosiast Fair enough. Will re-read and point out to you any inconsistencies with the original stated requirement if found. If the question is now clear to you, perhaps the question will be clear to other users, or you can tell them directly why, in your view, the question is clear now.

Comment: @PeterTaylor You could consider the _first_ entry the receipt or printout of the initial deposit. The "leap day" concerns have been addressed, above, correct? We are dealing with only `360` day years. And the question does not ask for defensive coding against bureaucracy  [What is the significance of 1/1/1753 in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310569/what-is-the-significance-of-1-1-1753-in-sql-server). Does that make sense to you?

Comment: 2. "*Is the addition of a before or after interest is calculated?*" This is still not addressed in the question or comments. 3 is addressed by lirtosiast's edit. 4. "*What if the periods aren't an integral number of days (as very few are)?*" is still not addressed in the question or comments. 5. "*How are leap years handled?*" is still not addressed in the question, which nowhere clearly explains the 360-day year mentioned in comments. 6. "*If the output is supposed to be for one year, why does it not end on year 2, day 0?*" is still not addressed adequately even in comments.

Comment: @PeterTaylor 2. The addition is added to the previously computed principal after interest applied. See the formula at the question. 4. Do not gather what you mean. 5. Leap years are irrelevant. The contract specifies 360 years at the question. 6. It does end at that point, if that is how you decide to view the output. The last entry is the complete 360 day year. Or, from your perspective, year 2, day 0.

Comment: 2. Great. Now please edit the *question* to state that, because comments are temporary. 4. If there are 7 periods, how are the days rounded?

Comment: 5. It doesn't. The only mention of 360 in the current version is "*The day number within a year; 0≤ day ≤360 e.g. days = 465 implies year = 2 and DOY = 100*" (so it seems that lirtosiast misunderstood you, because that implies 365 days per year). In the previous version the only mention was "*Initially set to 360, a banker's year; this input must be capable of being adjusted to a different period, for example, 360/12 monthly, or 360/4, quarterly*", which does not clearly say that all years have 360 days. 6. If year 1 has a day 0 and a day 360, it must have at least 361 days.

Comment: @PeterTaylor 2. There is no rounding. Will adjust question concerning "465"

Comment: @PeterTaylor Updated question

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, <s>115</s> 112 bytes

```
d=360
(r#t)n a=zipWith(\y x->(max(ceiling$y/d)1,until(<=d)(-d+)$y*d/n,y*d/n,x))[0..t*n].iterate(\x->x+(x*r)/n+a)
```

Function `#` takes the parameters in order r, t, n, a, p and returns a list of 4-tuples (year, day, days, principal).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzBasMwEAXv/YoH8WFly7bcQE91/yDnHJJSlko0S@2tUFSQ8/OuoJeZyzA3vn@HZdl3Px9f3BOlQzYKnh8Sz5JvdN1Q@jdaudBnkEX0q9lGbyb7q1kWep29od53ptlaP6r9ZzHm4oYht/o@SA6Jc6Br3ZSOSpvMqB2bfWVRzFg5nj4Qk2hGAzoYuMEdMWF6xuSqgb5H5MRrqCv8JF8pdySLbKEWbBFrtf8B)

Comment: Floating point numbers can be returned for `day` and `days` to save a few bytes. Does the program update `days` when `t` is `2`?

Comment: @guest271314: See output for t=2, n=360:  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYzNasMwEITvfYqB6CDZ8l8NOdV9g5xzaEpZXNEssbdCUUHuyzt7CQwzw@zyXel@C8uy7/M0B15Yfl5sOmQnoOmf45nz1V42lObdrlQwmNls3Xjs/Wz@JPNi38bj4GyjU@3MVml2osdnK8599G2bK/lsOYdEOdiL0kptS5VcJzW5fSUWTFgpnr4QE0uGgT049G0/4hWKwqAC0DSIlGgNysJv@lbnO5JH9hAP8oj6tT8A "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: Interesting. Got `3655.4199681711298` for day 360 here using JavaScript. The results at linked tio are `3655.419968171068`

Comment: @guest271314: maybe my code is one of the many online compound interest services mentioned in the introduction of your challenge that accumulates rounding errors.